# Put a shape on pictureBox, c#

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I have a pictureBox, I need to put some ovalshapes on different places over the pictureBox..

In some reason the shapes are behind the picture and they unseen..

Can I do something that the shapes will be over the picture and not behind it..?

What property change this?

Comment: What have you done so far?? Show your work to know that what are you doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

To paint some oval shapes you use a `List<Rectangle> ovals = List<Rectangle>();`

To draw them you have a choice of

- drawing them **into** the Image of the PictureBox or--
- **on top** of the PictureBox.

For the former you need to create the `Graphics` object from the `Image` you want to change:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
   foreach (Rectangle R in ovals)
        graphics.FillEllipse(yourBrush, R.X, R.Y, R.Width, R.Height);
if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

This code will change the pixels and can be put anywhere.

For the latter you use the `Paint` event:

```
foreach (Rectangle R in ovals)
   e.Graphics.FillEllipse(yourBrush, R.X, R.Y, R.Width, R.Height);
```

This version will only change the surface of the PicureBox and needs to be put in or be triggered from the Paint event.

I think you want this version..